# Decomposition of a continuous linear functional on $L^p$ into two positive continuous l.f.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Prove that if $I: L^p(\mu) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous linear functional then there exists $I^+$, $I^-$ continuous positive linear functionals such that $I=I^+ + I^-$.

I know the proof for the case that $I$ is a *bounded* linear functional. We define $I^+(f):=\sup\{I(g) : g \in L^p, 0\leq g \leq f\}$ and $I^-=I^+ - I$ and prove the statement.

But in this case I don't know what to do, and I can't link the proof for the bounded case because, of course, $I^+$ is defined with a supremum, which just make sense if we assume boundness of $I$ ... and I don't think that's a way to fix it.

My attempt was based on: try to define a continuous $I^+$ for simple functions and then use the fact that given $f\in L^p$ exist a sequence of simple functions $\varphi_n \to f$ and use continuity of $I^+$ to give $I^+ (f)$, but I can't do this in a useful way .

Anyone can help me?

Comment: $1\leq p<\infty$

Comment: Continuity is the same as bounded? $I$ is a linear map between normed spaces, so being continuous is the same as being bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $1<p<\infty$.By a well known result there exists $g \in L^{q}$ ($q=\frac p {p-1}$) such that $I(f)=\int fg$ for all $f \in L^{p}$ and all you have to do is define $I^{\pm}(f)=\int fg^{\pm}$. The same idea works for $p=1$ also.

Comment: Hmm... but if $f$ is negative can I conclude that $I^+(f) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: The usual definition of  a positive operator on a function space is $I^{+}f \geq 0$ if $f \geq 0$. There is no (non-zero) linear operator $T$ on $L^{p}$ for which $Tf \geq 0$ for all $f$, so you have to go back to your source and find the correct definitions.

Comment: that's right, because $T(f)=T(-(-f))=-T(-f)$ and can't be the case that both of them are positive! Thanks