Strictly positive linear functional: If there is one, there are infinitely many
Let $\mathbf{y}=\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in an
infinite-dimensional Lebesgue space $L^{p}(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F}
,\mathrm{P})$, $p\geq1$, on some probability space $(\mathsf{\Omega
},\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$. Let
$$
\mathsf{Y}=\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}:\mathbf{a}=\{a_{n}
\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\ell^{\infty}\right\}  \subset L^{p}
$$
be a proper subspace of $L^{p}$. Given $\mathbf{v}=\{v_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}
\in\ell^{1}$, and assume that there exists a positive continuous linear function
$f:L^{p}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $v_{n}=f(Y_{n}
)=\operatorname{E}(ZY_{n})$, with $Z>0$ and $Z\in(L^{p})^{\ast}$ (continuous
dual space of $L^{p}$), where $Z>0$ means $Z$ is strictly positive such that $\mathrm{P}(Z>0)=1$ and
$\mathrm{P}(Z\leq0)=0$
Show that we have an infinite number of positive linear functions such as
$v_{n}=f_{X}(Y_{n})=\operatorname{E}(XY_{n})$ with $X>0$ (strictly positive $\mathrm{P}(X>0)=1$) and $X\in
(L^{p})^{\ast}$.

If I can find a second one, then the convex combination will produce infinitely many of them. But how to find a second one? $\operatorname{E}(XY_{n})=\operatorname{E}(ZY_{n})$ with $Z\neq X>0$.

Are you asking about $f_X$ being different as a map $L^p\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or as $Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? If it is the later, then I don't think it is true (the $Y_n$ might form a Hilbert basis and that would uniquely determine $f$). On the other hand, if you mean the first, that is fairly easy if $Y$ is not dense in $L^p$ (if it is dense you are back in the case of $L^p$), as you don't specify what happens on $Y^\perp$ and so you have one free parameter to get uncountably many different $f_X$'s.

$L^{p}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, uncountably many different $X$, but how to make sure $Z\neq X$ and $X>0$. There exists at least one random variable in $L^{p}$ but not in the closure of $\mathsf{Y}$

Are the $Y_n$, respectively $v_n$ positive?

$v_n$ positive, but $Y_n$ may be $\mathrm{P}(Y_n>0)>0$ and $\mathrm{P}(Y_n<0)>0$ at the same time

How do you ensure then that $f$ will be a positive functional?

Also, do you assume the $Y_n$ to be linearly independent? I think you are missing plenty of assumptions.

for $Y_n$, we can purge the redundant terms, then there will be finite terms or countably infinite.  the positivity of $f$   is by assumption. In financial market, if it is free of arbitrage, there will exist a positive linear pricing function, where $v_n$ the price and $Y_n$ the future payoff

After a slight reframing, the question is really asking about the following: If $F \subset L^p$ is a proper closed subspace of $L^p$, does there exists two (and therefore uncountably many) different positive linear functionals $\varphi$ and $\psi$ on $L^p$ whose restrictions to $F$ are the same? This can be easily given by the following: Since $F \subset L^p$ is a proper closed subspace, there exists a nonzero bounded linear functional $\phi \in (L^p)^\ast$ s.t. $\phi$ is zero when restricted to $F$. Since every bounded linear functional on $L^p$ is the difference of two positive ones, we may write $\phi = \varphi - \psi$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are positive. Then $\varphi = \psi$ on $F$ but they are not equal on the entirety of $L^p$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3000586, seems it is hard to write out some explicit forms for the $X$, but we know the existence.

but how to make sure $\psi(Y_{n})=v_{n}$?

@ChenDeng-Ta Is your $v_n$ pre-fixed? In that case the result is false. Here is a finite-dimensional counterexample: in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $Y_1 = (1, 1, 0)$ and $Y_2 = (0, 0, 1)$. Its span is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there is only one positive $\psi$ s.t. $\psi(Y_1) = 0$ and $\psi(Y_2) = 1$, namely $\psi(a, b, c) = c$.

positive here means strictly positive, say, $Z>0$, not $Z\geq0$. The $Z$ in
$\psi(a,b,c)=c$ is $Z=(0,0,1)$, not strictly postive.

@ChenDeng-Ta You should edit your question to clarify that, then. Positive linear functionals basically always mean just positive, not strictly positive. Even if you wrote $Z > 0$, it will be usually be interpreted as just $Z \geq 0$, $Z \neq 0$.

@ChenDeng-Ta Here is a counterexample requiring strict positivity: Consider $L^2(0, 1)$. Fix $f \in L^2(0, 1)$ s.t. $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1)$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 1$. Let $Y_n$ be chosen so that they densely span ${f}^\perp$. Let $v_n$ be chosen s.t. $v_n = E(Y_n)$. Then the only positive linear functional satisfying the requisite conditions is the one corresponding to $Z = 1$.

@ChenDeng-Ta This is because any $Z$ with $E(ZY_n) = v_n$ would satisfy $E((Z - 1)Y_n) = 0$, so $Z - 1$ is orthogonal to all $Y_n$. Thus, $Z - 1 = cf$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. But the only positive function of the form $1 + cf$ is $1$, corresponding to $c = 0$.

Let
$$
f=\left{
\begin{array}
[c]{lll}
\left(  \ln\frac{1-x}{x}\right)  ^{1/2} &  & 0<x\leq1/2\
-\left(  -\ln\frac{1-x}{x}\right)  ^{1/2} &  & 1/2<x<1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $\operatorname{E}(f^{2})=2\ln2$ (Lebesgue measure). Now, does there
always exist ${Y_{n}}$ so that they densely span ${f}^{\perp}$?

@ChenDeng-Ta It doesn’t matter what $f$ is, ${f}^\perp$ is a separable Hilbert space, so it has a countable orthonormal basis. Just let $Y_n$ be that basis. (If you specifically want $\sum_n a_nY_n$ to converge for all $(a_n) \in l^\infty$, you need to renormalize the norm a bit. Say if $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of ${f}^\perp$, then let $Y_n = \frac{1}{n^2}e_n$.)

no matter what $f$ is, ${f}^{\perp}$ is a separable Hilbert space, why?

@ChenDeng-Ta $L^2(0, 1)$ is a separable Hilbert space. Any closed subspace of a separable Hilbert space is a separable Hilbert space. (If you’re unaware of this, I strongly suggest you review the basics of functional analysis. If I’m being honest and blunt, your posts on this site, your questions, and your responses to answers or comments all betray a quite significant lack of knowledge in the very basics of functional analysis.)

Thank you for your enthusiastic help! I feel lucky that you have accelerated my understanding of this interesting knowledge and helped me better understand the financial models to which this mathematics is applied.
